# Saving images from web

Tags: iphone

I am new to IOS development. I am developing an app in which i am viewing some images in my app that are stored on a server. The thing is that, i want an image from the server to store in my photo gallery. anyone know the procedure?

Thanks for every help;

Answer (score 1):

You will have implement web services to access images from server, so that it can be downloaded to your iPhone App.

Comment: i have already hit the webservice and able to view the images from the server in my app. Question is that , how to save it to the photo library

Answer (score 1):

Look up the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) for the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum function. It will save a UIImage to the camera roll.